# How to make this complex query more efficient?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

[image]

I want to select employees, having more than 10 products and older than 50. I also want to have their last product selected. I use the following query:

```
SELECT 
    PE.EmployeeID, E.Name, E.Age, 
    COUNT(*) as ProductCount,
    (SELECT TOP(1) xP.Name 
     FROM ProductEmployee xPE 
     INNER JOIN Product xP ON xPE.ProductID = xP.ID 
     WHERE xPE.EmployeeID = PE.EmployeeID 
       AND xPE.Date = MAX(PE.Date)) as LastProductName
FROM 
    ProductEmployee PE 
INNER JOIN 
    Employee E ON PE.EmployeeID = E.ID
WHERE 
    E.Age > 50
GROUP BY 
    PE.EmployeeID, E.Name, E.Age
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 10
```

Here is the execution plan link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rlp3bx10ty3c1mf/ximExPlan.sqlplan?dl=0

However it takes too much time to execute it. What's wrong with it? Is it possible to make a more efficient query?

I have one limitation - I can not use CTE. I believe it will not bring performance here anyway though.

Comment: are you able to look at the Query Execution Plan?  That is the first place to look.  Is Age a computed field?  A persons age is not static, it varies with time.  Normally Date of Birth would be stored.  You could put an non-unique, non-clustered index on AGE to speed it up possibly

Comment: @Cato thanks, I'll look at it. I can not alter DB structure, I would also use DoB if it was my design)

Comment: Also indexes on ProductEmployee - (A) employeeid, [date] and   (B) productId  -  could be tried

Comment: @Cato They are in place already

Comment: You have top 1 in a subquery but no order by. Without an order by you can't ensure which row will be returned. To be honest that subquery is quite odd. To help with the performance we would need to see the indexes for these tables and approximate row counts. From your diagram it looks like ProductEmployee has no primary key. Does it have a clustered index?

Comment: @Sean Lange ProductEmployee has clustered key (ProductId, EmployeeId). TOP 1 because it already has condition xPE.EmployeeID = PE.EmployeeID AND xPE.Date = MAX(PE.Date). It could be ordered by Date though instead. I'll try it, thanks

Comment: So you could probably remove top 1 then since that query only returns 1 row anyway. But for the original question, performance tuning is as much an art form as a science. There are many factors involved. Without the execution plan as requested we are guessing. It could stale statistics, poor indexing, etc.....

Comment: @AntonMaiorov note that in some RDMS, depending on version, is more efficient to replace int fields like `E.Age > 50` with `E.Age >= 51` and  .`COUNT(*) > 10` with `COUNT(*) > =11` . Could you change your query and test it?

Comment: @Horaciux Maybe there is a tiny perfomance benefit, but I can not catch it with my tools

Comment: You need to show us the query plan and also any indexes on the tables.  Otherwise we're just guessing (see answers so far).

Comment: Also, you say in comments to answers that your elapsed time is 106 ms.  How is 106 ms too slow?  That's way faster than human response/perception, and about the same as the best network transmission time you can reasonably hope for.  And if that's too slow then what is your target time?

Comment: @RBarryYoung I've added query plan link. 106 ms is because I did not have large enough DB at hand

Answer (score 2):

Before creating Index I believe we can restructure the query.

Your query can be rewritten like this

```
SELECT E.ID,
       E.NAME,
       E.Age,
       CS.ProductCount,
       CS.LastProductName
FROM   Employee E
       CROSS apply(SELECT TOP 1 P.NAME AS LastProductName,
                                ProductCount
                   FROM   (SELECT *,
                                  Count(1)OVER(partition BY EmployeeID) AS ProductCount -- to find product count for each employee
                           FROM   ProductEmployee PE
                           WHERE  PE.EmployeeID = E.Id) PE
                          JOIN Product P
                            ON PE.ProductID = P.ID
                   WHERE  ProductCount > 10 -- to filter the employees who is having more than 10 products
                   ORDER  BY date DESC) CS -- To find the latest sold product
WHERE  age > 50
```

Comment: This does not execute in SSMS, ProductCount is red

Comment: @AntonMaiorov - Missed alias name for `Cross Apply`. Check now updated

Comment: Ambiguous column name 'NAME', fifth line is red

Comment: Note: in some RDMS, depending on version, is more efficient to replace int fields like `ProductCount > 10 ` with `ProductCount >= 11 ` and `age > 50`with `age >= 51`. This prevent the engine to read all 10 value entries just for reaching the first grater value.

Comment: @AntonMaiorov - check now updated.. Those are very simple mistakes since I dont have ssms or your table to play around. Start doing debugging bro

Comment: @Prdp Sure, I do) Thanks for the efforts, however my query gives CPU time = 16 ms,  elapsed time = 106 ms. Your query gives CPU time = 4921 ms,  elapsed time = 4908 ms. On same data ofc

Comment: @AntonMaiorov - try now. refactored it a bit

Comment: CPU time = 15 ms,  elapsed time = 71 ms. I will add more data, otherwise it is not possible to distinguish

Comment: @AntonMaiorov - Again I changed it. check this as well

Comment: I've added more data, the queries still act approximately the same.

Comment: @AntonMaiorov mind showing how execution plan looks like?

Comment: @Evaldas Buinauskas Sure, here is the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/wugklp7rqs7vo8h/prdp.sqlplan?dl=0.

Comment: @AntonMaiorov Three table spools and sort, these are one of the most expensive operations. Try to add index like I've suggested `CREATE INDEX ix_Person_Age_Name ON Person (Age, Name);` and `CREATE INDEX ix_PersonEmploee_EmployeeID_Date ON ProductEmployee (EmployeeID, Date DESC);` They might speed things up and remove sorting operation.

Comment: @Evaldas Buinauskas 'INDEX ix_PersonEmploee_EmployeeID_Date ON ProductEmployee (EmployeeID, Date DESC);' made all the queries approximately 30% faster. Thank you!

Comment: @AntonMaiorov Could you show me plan again? :) Perhaps I'll see something else.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas Sure! I still find my initial query beeing faster (but with ProductEmployee.Date index). So I post execution plan for it. Here is the link, I: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rlp3bx10ty3c1mf/ximExPlan.sqlplan?dl=0

Comment: @AntonMaiorov http://prnt.sc/dz5lnt see underlined path. It's scanning full table to find employees older than 30. index on Age should help, sql server then should seek for records.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee AS E
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT PE.EmployeeID
    FROM ProductEmployee AS PE
    GROUP BY PE.EmployeeID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 10
    ) AS PE
    ON PE.EmployeeID = E.ID
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1) P.*
    FROM Product AS P
    INNER JOIN ProductEmployee AS PE2
        ON PE2.ProductID = P.ID
    WHERE PE2.EmployeeID = E.ID
    ORDER BY PE2.Date DESC
    ) AS P
WHERE E.Age > 50;
```

Proper indexes should speed query up.
You're filtering by `Age`, so followining one should help:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_Person_Age_Name
    ON Person (Age, Name);
```

Subquery that finds emploees with more than 10 records should be calculated first and `CROSS APPLY` should bring back data more efficient with `TOP` operator rather than comparing it to MAX value.

Answer by [@Prdp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3349551/prdp) is great, but I thought I'll drop an alternative in. Sometimes windowed functions do not work very well and it's worth to replace them with ol'good subqueries.

Also, do not use `datetime`, use `datetime2`. This is suggest by Microsoft:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx

> Use the **time**, **date**, **datetime2** and **datetimeoffset** data
>   types for new work. These types align with the SQL Standard. They are
>   more portable. **time**, **datetime2** and **datetimeoffset** provide
>   more seconds precision. **datetimeoffset** provides time zone support
>   for globally deployed applications.

By the way, here's a tip. Try to name your surrogate primary keys after table, so they become more meaningful and joins feel more natural. I.E.:

- In Employee table replace `ID` with `EmployeeID`
- In Product table replace `ID` with `ProductID`

I find these a good practice.

Comment: I just don't want to hit `ProductEmployee` table twice that's the reason I went for Window function. Thought of writing the same +1

Comment: P.Date is red on 16th line

Comment: @AntonMaiorov spotted issue. let me fix ;)

Comment: @Prdp I totally understand you. I'd prolly go the same way you did, but like I've mentioned in my comment. Why not to drop an alternative. :)

Comment: It works now, however I'm adding more data to see which one is faster. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
with usersOver50with10productsOrMore (employeeID, productID, date, id, name, age, products ) as  (
    select employeeID, productID, date, id, name, age, count(productID) from productEmployee 
    join employee on productEmployee.employeeID = employee.id  
    where age >= 50
    group by employeeID, productID, date, id, name, age
    having count(productID) >= 10 
    )
select sfq.name, sfq.age, pro.name, sfq.products, max(date) from usersOver50with10productsOrMore as sfq
join product pro on sfq.productID = pro.id
group by sfq.name, sfq.age, pro.name, sfq.products
;
```

There is no need to find the last productID for the entire table, just filler the last product from the results of employees with 10 or more products and over the age of 50.

Comment: What about the NAME of a last product? I also need the Name and Age of the employee ...

Comment: 1. While I didn't write this up for SSMS, I did use sqlite where it works well. This is basic sql, so I have to believe sql-server can handle nested selects. 2. If you really need the name of the product instead of its ID, then join the outer select to your product table. Backing up: the point my approach is only find the last product from the results of the first query since it will be far more efficient.

Comment: I've updated this to run in SSMS, see the complete DDL and SQL here:  http://rextester.com/ZMNP55650

Comment: It works now, but returns empty table. And I can not use CTE

Comment: @AntonMaiorov Are there any other limitations you care to divulge?

Comment: I'm sorry, should have told you earlier about CTE